# Consider removing the chain-tool tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Bicycles Exchange already has a tag for "tools" with its wiki as follows:

*Tools you use for repairing, maintaining, building, etc. Pump, **chain breaker**, wrenches, spoke tool, repair stand etc.*

There are currently 174 questions tagged with "tools" while there are currently zero questions tagged with "chain-tool" and it appears that it is currently covered by the tools tag based on its wiki.

Should the chain-tool tag be dropped (or made a tag synonym to tools)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[chain-tool](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chain-tool) is not an actual tag, it is a [synonym](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) for [chainbreaker](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chainbreaker).  Now, it appears that there are *no* questions tagged [chainbreaker](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chainbreaker) either, which suggests that the synonym should either be deleted or they should both be retargeted.